# How to re-create the partition table?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, raid, data-recovery, gpt

I accidentally dd the first 512 bytes using

> dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1

and the partition table is now gone. Is there ANY way to re-create the partition table(/dev/sdb).

My hard drive is **2X2TB Soft RAID**(GPT Partition Table)

```
root@rescue:/# parted -l
Model: ATA HGST HUS724020AL (scsi)
>Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name     Flags
 1      20.5kB  1049kB  1029kB                  primary  bios_grub
 2      2097kB  1987GB  1987GB                  primary
 3      1987GB  1992GB  5242MB  ext4            primary
 4      1992GB  2000GB  8388MB  linux-swap(v1)  primary


Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA HGST HUS724020AL (scsi)
>Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you are willing to try some manual edits to fix your partition table, see if the link helps in any way: http://askubuntu.com/questions/437272/how-to-fix-overlapped-partitions-in-the-mbr-table/437613#437613  `sfdisk -d /dev/sdX` dumps the partition table, but since you have deleted that you'd have to manually prepare one with right values of _start, size, ID_ and flags like _bootable_ for your GPT table (again, this is just the theory). After you create the right partition table layout in file say _gpt-layout.txt_, you can import it with `sfdisk /dev/sdX < gpt-layout.txt`

Comment: Using [google](https://www.google.se/?gfe_rd=cr&safe=off#q=restore%20partition%20table%20ubuntu&safe=off) seems to bring up some interesting items. An ubuntuforums posting (oldish) and references to Testdisk (software) - I'd recommend a look.